Is there a way to tell TypeScript that an external type has additional properties?
I'm using an external JS library in which additional properties are defined on a class prototype using Object.defineProperties(ClassName.prototype, ...).
Typescript, for some reason, doesn't recognize these properties (properties that defined in the constructor are recognized just fine).
This library has very poor typescript definition (many classes and properties are missing), so I can't use it.
Is there a way to tell TS that these properties are actually exist on this specific class?

Please provide a [mre] and we can try to show you how to do it. The answer below describes declaration merging, which is generally the way to do it... if it's not working for you, we need more debugging details.

You can 'extend' an class or interface definition just by declaring an interface with the same name. For example:
// Defined in module `bad-library`
class BadClass {
  constructor(public name: string) {}

  public getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

// This can go in a d.ts file
declare module 'bad-library' {
  export interface BadClass {
    address: string;
  }
}

import * from 'bad-library'
function test() {
  const badClass = new BadClass('name');
  badClass.address = 'address';    // works fine. 
  console.log(badClass.address);   // works fine. 
}

You can define as many interfaces with the same name as you like. This is how some libraries can provide type definitions on things they might monkey patch.

Thank you, but TS doesn't seem to understand that this extension refers to the same object which I import form a different location (despite I give it the same name, and put it in different d.ts file which I then imported). Did I do something wrong or an additional step is required?

It might need to use declaration merging. I've updated the example in the answer.

Your answer could be clearer if you used separate code blocks to indicate individual files. Also, the correct file extension is .d.ts, eg bad-library.d.ts
